# Differences in two grammars to parse the same expression

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, grammar

Let's say I have the following simplified SQL grammar:

```
select:
    SELECT distinct? selectItemList
   (FROM fromClause
   (WHERE whereClause)?)?
```

I have never worked much with parse trees, so I was wondering if the above would work better having the `FROM` and `WHERE` outside or within the respective clauses, or whether it doesn't matter either way?

For example, the above or the following:

```
select:
    selectClause
   (fromClause
   whereClause?)?
```

What would be the main difference between the two from a parsing standpoint, and which would be preferable? Note I know that some of these questions will often get tagged as 'opinion-based', but I am a beginner to parsing and curious to see what implications there will be downstream depending on the choice I make in the grammar.

---

Here is the first grammar and parse Tree:

```
grammar Select1;
root: selectStatement* EOF;

selectStatement
    : SELECT distinct? selectItemList
      (FROM fromClause
      (WHERE whereClause)?)?
  ;

distinct: DISTINCT;
selectItemList: selectItem (COMMA selectItem)*;
selectItem: expr;
fromClause: expr;
whereClause: expr;
expr
    : LPAREN selectStatement RPAREN
    | Atom
    ;


SELECT: 'SELECT';
FROM: 'FROM';
WHERE: 'WHERE';
DISTINCT: 'DISTINCT';
COMMA: ',';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';

Atom: [a-zA-Z]+ | [0-9]+;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

[image]

And here is the second:

```
grammar Select2;
root: selectStatement* EOF;

selectStatement
    : selectClause
     (fromClause
      whereClause?)?
  ;

selectClause
    : SELECT distinct? selectItemList
    ;

distinct: DISTINCT;
selectItemList: selectItem (COMMA selectItem)*;
selectItem: expr;
fromClause: FROM expr;
whereClause: WHERE expr;
expr
    : LPAREN selectStatement RPAREN
    | Atom
    ;


SELECT: 'SELECT';
FROM: 'FROM';
WHERE: 'WHERE';
DISTINCT: 'DISTINCT';
COMMA: ',';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';

Atom: [a-zA-Z]+ | [0-9]+;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

[image]

To me (in my naive opinion) the second parse tree seems like a bunch of needless indirection. Are there any benefits of either approach -- which one would be preferable and why?

Comment: It's easy to get carried away with general implementations of a Tree datastructure. Of course, if you want a CST (a la Antlr) then a general Tree implementation makes lots of sense. But (opinion here) in many ways, that's not very useful. The thing that's usually called an AST these days is not really a tree at all; it's a composite data structure in built up from heterogenous objects, each of which has specific members whose values are other node objects, or enumerated unions of node objects. In other words, is an idiosyncratic data structure designed for the particular language.

Comment: For a reasonably well-documented example applied to a not-too-complicated but real-life language, take a look at Python's [AST module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). The underlying parser, including the AST construction and the AST object definitions themselves, is mostly machine generated with a custom tool from a grammar and an AST object description. So it's a pretty good learning tool, particularly if you understand Python.

Comment: Also, find a copy of a good compiler text (either the Dragon book, for historical veracity, or Dick Grune's Modern Compiler Design, or whatever else you can find), and read the section on Attribute grammars. An AST is really the result of computing the attributes for each parse node, where many of the attributes are simply (labeled) child references. A few days of reading will teach you a lot more than disjointed Q&A on this site. Do the exercises! Good luck.

Comment: @rici thanks yea I'm looking to read the Grune's Parsing book too.

Comment: @rici in terms of the above choices though, do you see one as inherently better than the other? Or is the distinction pretty trivial in the above is what you're saying?

Comment: Unlike some contributors to this site, I'm not a big fan of CSTs. I understand why Antlr generates them, and I understand why Parr chose not to continue with a more general and less maintainable AST formalism as existed in previous Antlr versions, but for practical parsing, I want a real semantic structure. The big advantage of CSTs is that if you are rigid about keeping all the data, it's easy to recreate the original input; that's good for certain purposes (syntax highlighting; code editors; that sort of thing). But the intermediate form shown in your images doesn't cut it for me. YMMV

Comment: NB Your grammars are not equivalent. The first one is missing the final `?`.

Comment: @user207421 fixed (I think).